# How do I create a conditional format with 2 columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, highlighting

I am trying to create a rule that would highlight a cell under these conditions:
Column B>1 & Column C=O

I want Column C to highlight if they meet these two conditions. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

The conditional formatting formula I would apply to column C is:

```
=AND(INDIRECT("RC",FALSE)=0,INDIRECT("RC[-1]",FALSE)>1)
```

The `FALSE` arguments to `INDIRECT` indicate it should use RC-style references instead of A1-style references. An RC-style reference of `RC` refers to the same cell, while the `RC[-1]` notation indicates the cell of the same row and one column to the left (the square brackets indicate a relative, rather than absolute, reference).